# Aprender paso a paso a utilizar RecyclerView en Android

Tags: android

Estoy intentando implementar un RecyclerView de una lista en horizontal en una aplicación que estoy creando y aunque he encontrado varios ejemplo de uso, en todos, solo muestran el código sin explicar detalladamente para que sirve cada cosa.

Tengo un ejemplo en mi aplicación que funciona correctamente, pero es un copia/pega de un ejemplo y quiero aprender como se utiliza sin necesidad de copiar y pegar cuando lo necesite.

Para aclararos mis dudas, sé que para utilizar un RecyclerView se utiliza un LayoutManager, un Adapter con ViewHolder y una clase DataSet que es la clase objeto que se utilizará para recoger todos los datos que se mostrarán en la lista, pero no sé para que se utiliza el LayoutMaganer ni el ViewHolder ni como trabajan juntos.

Seria de gran ayuda que me explicarais como funciona el RecyclerView y si es muy extenso, os pido que dejéis como comentario algún enlace en el que se explique mi duda.

Comment: me gusta esta pregunta, si bien es bastante extensa, si logramos algunas buenas respuestas seria una gran material para el sitio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Después de todo el fin de semana dándole vueltas al asunto, he conseguido poner en marcha un RecyclerView en horizontal entendiendo brevemente para que se utiliza cada componente.

Pues bueno, he encontrado esta pagina que explica detalladamente para que sirver cada elemento:

https://erikcaffrey.github.io/2015/10/05/recyclerview/

Y para realizar un ejemplo de un `RecyclerView`, me recomendaron la siguiente página web:

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Esta página esta en inglés, pero explica todos los pasos a seguir para crea un `RecyclerView` correctamente y siguiendo todos los pasos pude comprender para que se utiliza cada cosa. Para quien no comprenda el inglés, le garantizo que utilizando el traductor lo entenderá perfectamente.

También tengo que decir que tuve algunos fallos con el código mostrado en la página de AndroidHive.

Resulta que en el método `onCreate()` del archivo `MainActivity.java` se llama al método `prepareMovieData()` en ultimo lugar, cuando tendria que llamarse justo después de declarar el RecyclerView, es decir, justo despues de esta línea:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

Si esta llamada la declaramos en último lugar, nos aparecerá un error de que el Objeto que hemos creado (en el caso de AndroidHive es la clase Movies) esta a null, es decir, que no tiene ningún dato.

Por otra parte, al final del método `prepareMovieData()` se declara la siguiente línea:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

A mi personalmente, esta línea me provoca un fallo en la aplicación que provoca que la App se cierre, quitándola del código me funciona perfectamente. Realmente, no se para que sirve esta línea, pero agradecería que si alguien sabe el por qué, que editara esta entrada explicándolo.

Por último, quería aclarar que la intención de este post era el crear un `RecyclerView` en horizontal, por lo que dejo a continuación la explicación para que un `RecyclerView` se muestre en horizontal o en vertical.

En el método `onCreate()` del archivo `MainActivity.java` le añadimos un LayoutManager al RecyclerView con las siguientes lineas:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Este LayoutManager se encarga de decir al RecyclerView como se mostraran los datos que introduzcamos, es decir, si aparecerá el contenido en vertical, en horizontal, en forma de lista, etc.. Por lo que si queremos que nuestra lista aparezca en **horizontal** solamente tenemos que editar las lineas anteriores por las siguientes:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

En caso de querer la lista en **vertical**, dejamos las lineas como están.

Espero que les sirva y gracias por lo apoyos.