# Crear un RecyclerView con desplazamiento horizontal y vertical a la vez

Tags: android, android-layout

Hace unas semanas que estoy aprendiendo a utilizar el `RecyclerView`. Mi intención principal para aprender a utilizarlo, era que necesitaba implementar una lista horizontal, es decir, que al girar el dispositivo en modo landscape (horizontal) apareciese de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de mucho buscar, encontré la forma detallada de poder implementarlo (cómo cree el desplazamiento horizontal del `RecyclerView`, [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6717/aprender-paso-a-paso-a-utilizar-recyclerview-en-android/6925#6925)), pero me encontré con otro problema. El ítem del `RecyclerView` era más grande que el alto del dispositivo (en landscape, horizontal), por lo que necesito crear un desplazamiento vertical y horizontal a la vez.

He mirado el Android Developer los métodos de la clase LayoutManager, pero mis conocimientos no son tan altos como para entender la mayoría de los métodos que existen, he probado también a meter dentro de un RecyclerView en vertical otro RecyclerView en horizontal con todo el contenido, pero me da error de `IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager` al que he encontrado, como solución, quitar todos los `<View.../>` del archivo XML, pero no da resultado alguno, y como no, he buscado por miles de paginas de Internet, pero se ve que nadie se a planteado esto o no es posible.

Para aclarar lo que pido con esta entra es, que alguien me diga si esto es posible y si tiene una posible idea de como implementarlo (aunque no sepa si es posible) y si no es posible que me explique el por que.

Comment: cuantas filas de elementos tendrias verticalmente, solo una?

Comment: Acabo de modificar la imagen para detallarlo un poco mejor, pero cada ítem del RecyclerView en horizontal se compone por una especie de cabecera con dos TextView, luego seis TextView separados por <View../> y otro elemento como la cabecera.

Comment: Es posible, pero se considera un anti patron.

Comment: Hola @UlisesMartinezadon , ¿podrías explicarme a que te refieres con "se considera un anti patrón"? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estaba tan enfadada por todos los problemas que había tendido con la aplicación que no había pensado en la solución mas sencilla.

Resulta que un RecyclerView se compone de dos archivos XML, uno principal donde se declara el RecyclerView y otro con el contenido de dicho item del RecyclerView.

La solución más sencilla y más tonta era introducir el RecyclerView dentro de un ScrollView. Así podre mover todos los items a la vez verticalmente gracias al ScrollView y también podré mover horizontalmente los items gracias al RecyclerView en modo horizontal.

Dejo aquí el archivo principal del RecyclerView como muestra:

`activity_main.xml`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardIn_margin_ext">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Pero no entiendo si pones width match parent, porque quieres desplazamiento horizontal?

Comment: @Webserveis no me había fijado en ello, pero si, debería ser `wrap_content` tanto en el  `ScrollView` como en el `RecyclerView` para que se adapten al contenido. Fallos del copia-pega entre proyectos, lo siento. Modifico en breve, aunque de todas formas, funciona bien de las dos formas. Gracias por fijarte. :)

Answer (score 1):

Claro que es posible, lo que tienes que hacer es lo que has investigado, crear un `LinearLayoutManager` horizontal que contendrá `RecyclerView` :

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
RecyclerView myListHorizontal = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_horizontal);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

que son las vistas que se reciclarian Horizontalmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y dentro de cada elemento horizontal agregar un `RecyclerView`,

```
RecyclerView verticalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_recycler_view_vertical, null);
verticalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
addView(verticalRecyclerView);
```

que contendrá vistas que se reciclarian verticalmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Elenasys, tu respuesta no es la que buscaba, pero me ha abierto los ojos a diferentes opciones que me servirán en otros proyectos que estoy realizando. Acabo de descubrir como realizar lo que estoy preguntando y era la cosa mas sencilla que me podría haber imaginado. Gracias de verdad por intentar ayudarme.